# Looping through a CSV file in order to send statements to an LRS

Tags: tin-can-api

Is there a utility that allows me to loop through a CSV file giving me the ability to send multiple statements to an LRS? My CSV file would have the necessary Actor, Verb, Object information in it all separated by commas.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an existing commercial utility, [Watershed LRS](http://watershedlrs.com) has exactly that functionality; you can upload a csv and it generates statements.

I'm sure you could create something fairly quickly in your chosen programming language using one of the [Tin Can code libraries](http://tincanapi.com/libraries) too.